# Edit an image brightness while using Slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget, flutter-slider, flutter-card

I'd like to edit an image brightness while using `Slider` in Flutter. Edit the brightness, contrast, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`adjustColor`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/adjustColor.html) function. It is possible to adjust:

1. blacks
2. whites
3. mids
4. contrast
5. saturation
6. brightness
7. gamma
8. exposure
9. hue

There are [other functions available here](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/image-library.html).